# Regression trees with time series data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series

So for one of my statistics courses I was tasked with a classic data analysis final project.

Our university gym has a tweeter account that reports the number of people in the facility. I was able to scrape about 6 months of traffic data as well as hourly weather records for that time frame. Now I am supposed to use some sort of tree for this assignment.

My data is formatted so that there is a value for every hour of every day for the 6 months of time. This includes when the gym is closed. Now I'm having some complications as I do not know where to go from here.

Should I decompose the time series and somehow use lag as a variable? Should I just make a dummy variable with the day of the week and hour?

Any input would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to predict from what?